# Regex to match a changing URL

Tags: notepad++, regex

I would like a regex to find a bunch of URLs but with the same domain.

Here's for example what I'm trying to find (and replace)

```
url(//static.parastorage.com/services/santa-resources/resources/viewer/user-site-fonts/fonts/Japanese/Matisse/v1/WAT-MatisseProN-DB.woff2)
```

The concept is, the regex will be able to find any url containing that domain and ending with a `)`

Thank you.

Comment: What is wanted  replacement? Please, edit your question and add some lines and expected result.

Comment: The replacement is really not important, for the moment I'm looking for how to match with that pattern that starts with that domain and ends with a ")".

Answer (score 0):

This could be one option.
`^.*static\.parastorage\.com.*\)$`

Explanation as follow:
`^` match start of line
`.` is a wildcard that will match any single character
`*` will match the previous element zero or more times
I.e `.*` will match any character zero or more times

In `\.` and `\)` the backslash will escape to literally match the dot `.` and the parenthesis `)`

`$` will match end of string

You will have to untick the `. matches newline` option.
[. matches new line picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDUk6.png)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, that actually matches all links except for the ones I'm looking for (with that domain exactly).

Comment: How did it go? Did you find the solution? You can always update with writing your own answer. If not, maybe you can give a more detailed example, like an extended text  of the URLs and exactly what you expect to match and not match. It would make it easier to help you further. Did you elaborate on the page @8ctopus recommended? What was your outcome from that?

Comment: I did not succeed using any regex, I eventually gave up and replaced everything manually. I still can't get your solution to work for similar situations or I would've gladly accepted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating on @akane's answer and knowing replacements will be involved later on, I would suggest capturing the different parts as follows

```
(.*?)(static\.parastorage\.com)(.*?)\)$
```

Experiment with the regex: https://regex101.com/r/gNG8AN/1.